# Script to query the google API and return the search position of a url for multiple terms?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to write a script that would access the google api pass a url and a list of search terms and then return the search position of each of those key terms for that url. Is this a simple enough task or even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible.  Your question is a bit too vague to provide a better answer than "Yes", though.

Do be aware that the position of a site in search results can vary by location and the Google site you use (e.g., if you're in the UK, using www.google.co.uk, I'd expect a UK website to rank higher than it would if you're in the US, using www.google.com).

<strike>The [Google Custom Search API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) is likely to be helpful to you.</strike> Sorry, this documentation is for site-specific searches (i.e. searching your own website), not Google in general.

You haven't actually said what language you intend to use, but there's Perl modules on CPAN which would make the task quite easy, for instance [Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Google-Search).

Comment: Thanks David. Sorry if the question was a bit vague. Do you know where abouts in the documentation i should be looking? Everything i have come across relates to adding a custom search box to a website

Comment: Languages i am familier with are Javascript, JSON etc & PHP